# Play Framework - production configuration threads/db connections for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework

We have a Play Framework application and we are running into production issues. I am curious what settings people have used on your production.conf to ensure that your web server does not slow down. We have a basic web application that communicates with Mysql, sends emails, text messages, and has a login portal.

If you're using an AWS EC2 instance (say a t2.large) how many threads to you set on your thread pool, how many connections on your database connection pool and what is your Xms and Xmx for memory set at?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you're using an AWS EC2 instance (say a t2.large) how many threads to you set on your thread pool

I think this might one of the possible root cause of issues you face with. Having a single `ThreadPool`, or more precisely `ExecutionContext` which wraps some `ExecutorService` (e.g. `FixedThreadPoolExecutorService`) is considered as bad practice, because it same `EC` instance inside of application can be used for blocking operations, like database access - for instance MySql in your case, which eventually will cause entire thread blocking, and performance issues in other app parts, like new connection handling or response rendering.

What you will need to do is to use different `EC` instances for blocking and non-blocking operations - let's call them `frontend EC` (for non blocking) and `backend EC` (for blocking).

- `frontend EC` you need to use in view and service levels (API controllers, business logic etc.);
- `backend EC` you you need to use in DAO application level or any possible blocking pars;

The way how resource should be distributed between those two `EC`'s is really depends on the context. You can start with for instance 80% of threads for `frontend EC` and other 20% `backend EC` and then keep tuning, until you will receive desired performance result.

But in general, question you ask depends on a lot of context - there is not silver bullet as usually at engineering.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Related to your answer -- we have noticed when we receive 80 hits per second, Play will receive GET calls really fast, but POST calls are delayed by 5-10 seconds. That is, a POST http call will not even be sent to the Controller from the Routes until 10-20 seconds later under heavy use. Would you know the cause for this? When this happens there is plenty CPU and memory on the machine.

Comment: @somid3 This question requires a lot of context and details, I'm afraid I won't be able to provide a good answer because of that. Instead, I'd suggest to perform some performance profiling using tools like VisualVM or Jprofile to find possible places of issues. Based on what you described, you can check also `BodyParser` performance or any logic related to handling request body - this is the first difference between GET and POST  requests handling I can notice, which can lead to such issues. Excuse me, if this my comment did not satisfy you.